# Preventing manga books from having yellow pages

Tags: merchandise

I just started collecting mangas I wonder how am I going to prevent them from having yellow pages. Currently, I store them in a glass shelf without a cover.

Are there any other ways?

Comment: IIRC yellowing (which is a general problem with books) is related to the quality of the paper used by the printers; I'm not sure how much of it can be avoided after the fact.

Comment: If you don't want to have problems with preserving the book, read/buy digital manga, but that's a different question and personal preference :)

Answer (score 10):

Although I have no manga, I do have a large comic book collection. I protect them with "comic book bags" (or sleeves) and anti-acidic cardboard.  They are stored in special boxes designed for comic books.  These supplies are also available and fitted for manga.  You can store 1 or 2 books per bag.  If two, you place them back to back, with an anti-acidic card in-between.

There are several vendors.  The one I use is [Bags Unlimited](http://www.bagsunlimited.com/), which has been around since 1976.  They have a huge number of "archival supplies" for comics, books, CDs, magazines, you name it.

I just read @Maroon's comment. Once yellowed and brittle, you can't do much about it.  But the purpose of the anti-acidic paper is to minimize damage to the books in the first place by helping neutralize the acids in the paper stock of the books.

Answer (score 3):

Yellow pages is a symptom of sun damage, more or less what happens when you leave something exposed to the sun for prolonged periods of time.  A good example of this is if you ever go to a comic shop and they have posters in the window that are really faded, it's the minor amounts of radiation from the sun more or less bleaching those colors away.

A good way to combat and prevent this is to keep them in a bookshelf and keep them organized, and if there are windows in the room just don't leave the blinds open all day.  It wont 100% prevent this issue, as @Maroon pointed out certain papers will just do this overtime.  However speaking from my experience doing this is an easy and effective way to help prevent this.