# What is a good way to protect manga from yellowing in an open bookself besides book covers/comic book bags?

Tags: merchandise

Recently I've started to collect manga. I have twenty-four volumes now. I keep them in an open bookshelf facing a window along with some other books which unfortunately I don't have any place for where it isn't facing the window, so I can't really keep them out of the sunlight. My fear of my books yellowing has been growing especially since the manga pages are so thin. I don't really like the idea of having to put each volume in one of those plastic comic book covers, so I was thinking of maybe putting a strip of white sheet behind them to minimize the impact the light has on them? I also have other books on the shelf that wouldn't necessarily fit comic bags. Is that a good idea, or would it just absorb more heat and further damage the books? Also, if anyone has any other methods, please share them. I’m open to buying stuff if I need to. I only have 20 volumes so it doesn’t need to be something huge (for now :D) Otherwise, the dimensions I need to cover are roughly 1.5 by 7 feet. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Addressing the suggested answers to the duplicate question suggestion and why I think it should be reopened, that question was answered with the comic protector sleeve option which I stated I did not want to do. I was asking specifically about other methods and if the method of hanging a portion of a cut white sheet behind the shelf would work. I would also be open to putting something else behind the shelf. Hopefully this is able to be reopened now, I think its probably different enough from the duplicate now but I can edit it further if need be.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Preserving manga book](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/40554)

Comment: RE Edit: the top answer also suggests "anti-acidic cardboard" and a site for archival supplies such as [Manga Graphic Novel Storage Boxes](https://www.bagsunlimited.com/category/170/manga-graphic-novel-storage-boxes) while the other answer does suggest keeping them out of the sunlight

Comment: as for your paper idea, i fear it might be too thin. though while i am are not in the same situation if i was i personally would think about getting something a bit thicker and sturdier like using [this spacer](https://www.bagsunlimited.com/product/6233/scored-spacer-for-comic-boxesbr-made-from-200-lb-test-white-corrugated-cardboardbrfold-on-scores-as-box-fills-up) to act as a shield. the white should absorb less heat with what it's meant to be for it'll stand better than paper and if you organize your shelf you can write on the front of them what is behind

Comment: Thanks for the input! I, however, am a little confused. I never mentioned a paper idea. My idea was to put a sheet behind the open area that's facing the sun.

Comment: I want to be able to see them so I'm not really interested in putting them in any sort of box.

Comment: Is this question eligible for being re-opened?